# Issue with installing netshell/paypal dev-master in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am using laravel 6 with php version 7.4.13 and the problem I am facing is that when I update my composer to set up my project it is showing me the error

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:                                                           
Class 'Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider' not found                                                           

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

and to resolve that when I install netshell/paypal with `composer require netshell/paypal dev-master`

it is shoiwing me error like

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires netshell/paypal dev-master -> satisfiable by netshell/paypal[dev-master].
- netshell/paypal dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I don't know why is this happen I have update my composer json code given below

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet": "^1.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "gabrielbull/ups-api": "^0.8.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "instamojo/instamojo-php": "^0.4.0",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository": "dev-master",
        "mehedi-iitdu/laravel-paystack": "dev-master",
        "mehedi-iitdu/paypal": "dev-master",
        "nexmo/laravel": "^2.2",
        "razorpay/razorpay": "2.0.0",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.3",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.29",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": ["app/Http/Helpers.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

also I am uploading my providers and aliases from config.php/app.php

```
    'providers' => [

    /*
    * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
    */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,
    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
    Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider::class,
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
    Mehedi\Paystack\PaystackServiceProvider::class,
    MehediIitdu\CoreComponentRepository\CoreComponentRepositoryServiceProvider::class,
    Nexmo\Laravel\NexmoServiceProvider::class,
    Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
    Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\PaytmWalletServiceProvider::class,
    \Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
    /*
    * Package Service Providers...
    */

    /*
    * Application Service Providers...
    */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
    'Paypal' => Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal::class,
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
    'Paystack' => Mehedi\Paystack\Facades\Paystack::class,
    'Nexmo' => Nexmo\Laravel\Facade\Nexmo::class,
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
    'PaytmWallet' => Anand\LaravelPaytmWallet\Facades\PaytmWallet::class,
    'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
],
```

can anybody please help me in this?

Comment: Try composer require netshell/paypal --dev

Comment: @Bapi Actually project is already live and I am new for this project and is error only happens with my system so for me every one can not change their coding

Comment: the package you try to install is supported for laravel 5, might not compatible with laravel 6

Comment: does the composer.json of others(others here is project's composer.json as you are saying the project is already in use) match with your composer.json